# ArcGIS Desktop 10.0 -- layout Data Frame Grid color inversion on export or print when other rasters are active

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap, raster

Having a problem with ArcMap 10.0 SP1 Data Frame Grid of graticule inverting color on export or when printing.

Occuring on multiple classroom PCs all working with the same datasets. Exporting to raster formats (PNG, JPEG) with resolution set under 149 dpi layout renders correctly.  But with any higher resolution, or for export to a mixed vector raster mode (PDF, AI) the Data Frame Grid inverts color (gradicule goes white--remainder of grid layer is solid black).  As this is the top layer of the map layout it renders the map useless.  Also, it does not occur when raster layers in the MXD are all turned off, just when one raster is active.

I assume the Data Frame Grid from the layout is converted to a raster layer as part of the print or export by some library. Does anyone have a good grasp of where this occurs and how the conversion can be adjusted to prevent inversion for reliable printing and export results?

Comment: Is there any rotation in the Data Frame? There is a known issue with that. Also ecw images can cause the issue you are mentioning. We print to file .prn the use PosterJet high end RIP (Raster Image Processing) software to rasterise directly to the printer (HP5000PS customised).

Comment: No rotation, had seen the past problems with that at 9.1, fixed at 9.2

Answer (score 1):

I experienced a similar problem, when the raster already had pyramids from an older ArcGIS version. Rebuilding the pyramids file fixed it (possibly you also have to delete the .ovr file before).

Comment: That seems possible. Raster was being downloaded and added from a local folder. Will work with the faculty member to recreate the exercise--might take a bit to set up again. Will post back.